# ASP.NET Web API authorized using Azure AD: Authorization has been denied

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I secured some of my ASP.NET Web API using Azure AD as you can see in the code screenshot below:

[image]

The strange thing is that **sometimes** when calling the API in parallel (bulk calls) the client gets an error:

> Authorization has been denied for this request

I am unable to detect why it happens only sometimes even if the client re-tries the call with another access token. Is there a way to find/debug the exact reason why? It is maybe because I need to resize the Web/DB(DTU) servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to Enable PII logging in the `startup.cs` file in `configure services` method to check for the proper error.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    // Enable PII logging
    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
   ...
}
```

*This error*: `Authorization has been denied` for this request usually occurs when there is ***`audience mismatch`*** or when the audience doesn’t match the one web api is expecting which is set in ValidAudience . The audience can be appid or appIdUri according to the application.

[image]

So in place  validAudience, please use tokevalidationparameters.validaudiences  or ***`ValidAudiences`***  to add both the `clientID` and the `AppIdURI` (`ap://<appIdUri>`) in place of AUDIENCE1 and AUDIENCE2

```
ValidateIssuer = true,
ValidAudiences = new List<string> 
        {
            "AUDIENCE1",
            "AUDIENCE2" 
        }
```

with such configuration, the api call can be validated for both the cases.

Comment: What if I set 'ValidateAudience = false'? Is it safe?

Comment: I also want to mention that I am not using the .CoreMVC but AspNet.MVC framework.

Comment: ValidateAudience , ValidateIssuer ..etc . are for validating the incoming token to check if it the token that is meant for your api for prescribed criteria and allow it accordingly. `ValidateAudience=true` validates if the recipient of the token is authorized to receive .According to the requirement, you may consider them or bypass them if not needed to validate .see [this](https://referbruv.com/blog/scenario-bypassing-jwt-token-validation-in-an-authentication-middleware/).